# Is there a way to get double quotes in json.loads method

Tags: python, json

I need to prepare input data for a API in json format.

I am using `json.loads()` function but it is returning data with single quotes. I have tried to convert data into strings and added double quotes but that does not help.

```
import json
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('..\\dummy_api_data.csv')

dict_data = data.to_dict(orient='records')
data_json_dump = json.dumps(dict_data, default='str')

json_data = json.loads(data_json_dump)
```

Output :- `{'name': 'Shawna', 'age': 46, 'salary': 119090}`

Expected Output:- `{"name": "Shawna", "age": 46, "salary": 119090}`

Comment: `json.loads` returns a dict; the single quotes are just Python's way of rendering a value of type `str`. If you need JSON, that's what the output of `json.dumps` (i.e., `data_json_dump`) is.

Comment: Your output is not json, it's python `dict`. You already have json string in `data_json_dump`, so you can print it and get expected result.

Comment: why do you need double quotes over single?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *need* double-quoted strings? In Python, single- and double-quoted strings are equivalent (except you can't use single quotes inside a single-quoted string without escaping, and vice versa for double-quoted strings).

Comment: API accepts data with double quotes only so when i am loading data using json.loads() output is as mentioned above and when i send it using post requests i am getting error

Comment: whats the error? I suspect this isn't the actual issue

Comment: The double quotes are needed because, JSON syntax is not Python syntax. JSON requires double quotes for its strings

Comment: @rahuldesai: If the API requires JSON, then don't pass it the raw `dict`, pass it the result of `json.dumps` (which will use double-quotes, because JSON requires them).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the content-type json to your header

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```